# python localhost request on same localhost with different port

Tags: python, elasticsearch, localhost

I'm using Flash in the localhost (`http://localhost:5000`) and trying to use python requests to request json result from elasticsearch

Here's my code

```
@app.route('/test')
def TestElasticsearch():
  url = "http://localhost:9200/customer/_search?q=James&size=5"
  r = requests.get(url)
  print r
  return r.text
```

When I access `http://localhost:5000/test` via google chrome, it returns

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /customer/_search?q=James&size=5 (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Note that I've tried accessing `http://localhost:9200/customer/_search?q=James&size=5` via google chrome and it works.

Please help me figure out the problem

Comment: try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:

@app.route('/test')
def TestElasticsearch():
    import urllib
    url = 'http://localhost:9200/customer/_search?q=James&size=5'
    # GET is the default action
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)  
    # Output from the GET assuming response code was 200
    r = response.read()   
    print r
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it doesn't work. `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused`